# XIki Command Not Found

Tags: command-line

I have been working tirelessly to "try" and get xiki [A shell console with GUI features](http://xiki.org/) to work on my 12.04 system to no avail. I installed it through [Ruby Version Manager](https://rvm.io/) and it installed well "I think". But when I try running the "xiki" shell command it refuses to run with an error "xiki command not found".

Please help. Any forthcoming help is appreciated :)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally found a fix to my problem thanks to @jrg. The following fixed my issue

```
rvm use --create 1.9.3@xiki; gem install xiki; which xiki
```

and then finally xiki. That worked perfectly!

Hope it fixes anyone else's problems :).